# Is it true that different devices choose which convention to use for defining a pixel?

Tags: css, user-interface, pixel, display

I'm reading about pixel sizes from [the documentation here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#x39), and it says the following:

> For a CSS device, these dimensions are either anchored (i) by relating
>   the physical units to their physical measurements, or (ii) by relating
>   the pixel unit to the reference pixel. For print media and similar
>   high-resolution devices, the anchor unit should be one of the standard
>   physical units (inches, centimeters, etc). For lower-resolution
>   devices, and devices with unusual viewing distances, it is recommended
>   instead that the anchor unit be the pixel unit. For such devices it is
>   recommended that the pixel unit refer to the whole number of device
>   pixels that best approximates the reference pixel.

**What I Want To Know:**

1) "`For a CSS device`": is a CSS device any device that can display an app that uses CSS? What would be an example of a non-CSS device? An old TV or something?

2) (main question) It says "`for print media...the anchor unit should be...`", whereas "`for low-resolution devices...it is recommended that the anchor unit be...`": I understand that the two options for anchoring the pixel are 1) make it relative to an inch, and 2) make it the reference pixel. So when they're making a given device, do they choose either (1) or (2) for px values for apps on that device? Like on an iPhone 1px might be the reference pixel, whereas on a TV it might be 0.75*(1/72) inches?